# Vue + Nuxt js: How to apply dynamic active class to parent menu using bootstrap navbar

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am new to vue + nuxt.js

I am using bootstrap navbar. See this [link](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar/)

I have following code.

```vue
<b-nav-item-dropdown type="dark">
  <template slot="button-content">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Users
  </template>
  <b-dropdown-item ref="users" to="/users" nuxt-link-active="/users">
    Listing
  </b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/users/add" nuxt-link-active="/users/add">
    Add new user
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
<b-nav-item-dropdown bg-transparent>
  <template slot="button-content">
    <i class="fas fa-users"></i> Teams
  </template>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/teams" nuxt-link-active="/teams">
    Listing
  </b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/teams/add" nuxt-link-active="/teams/add">
    Add new team
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

Now i want a parent menu to be open when child is clicked. In current scenario when i click on Team Listing, it closes the parent div so cannot identify which menu is open. Also when i click on user listing it should close team menu.

I tried many way by googling. But cannot find proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled into this question. Here is my answer if you still need it.

You should not use `nuxt-link-active` in a Bootstrap Vue element.

You may rather use :

```html
<b-dropdown-item to="/teams" exact exact-active-class="active">
   Listing
</b-dropdown-item>
```